# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30_2 was killed

Tags: installation, android-emulator

I have just installed Android Studio on Windows 10. I am having all sorts of issues. The first, of many, is that I cannot get the emulator to work. I have tried the following:

1. Clicked software instead of hardware.
2. Restarted computer.
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled the emulator.
4. Clicked on all updates.
5. Googled troubleshooting answers, nothing.

It always comes up with the same error: "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30_2 was killed."

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your Windows installation doe snot use HyperV (used by sandboxing, WUA2 and some other Windows features). Use this command to check: https://superuser.com/a/1538529/62676. If you execute the command it should not print any text, othewiese you have HyperV activated.

Answer (score 2):

"emulator ___ process was killed" can be multiple reasons.

1. check if your machine having enough RAM support as starting emulator consumes too much memory.
2. You don't to select "hardware" or "software", select for automatic option in graphics options.

Work around can be, just create a light weighted emulator 1st and try to use, then use Pixel 2 with latest os. This will help to narrow down your issue in analysis.

Comment: Emulating an older phone model with lower hardware requirements worked, and helped me narrow down the issue on Ubuntu. Turned out the disk partition containing `~/.android/avd` was full, so had to move+symlink it to a another partition with more space available.